# [VB.NET][ACCESS] How do I check for if a database exists?

Tags: database, vb.net

I cant find anything online to help.

I want to create a table if it doesnt already exist, or populate a listbox with what is stored in said table if it DOES exist. All I have so far is the populate and create table subroutines, but have no idea how to check the database so far.

Thank you

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to check whether the DB exists or the table exists?

Comment: You do know the difference between a database and a database table?

Comment: Aplologies. I want to find if there is a specific table within my database.

Comment: Is your code in a Form inside of Access, or is your code in another application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking if an MSAccess **DATABASE** exists or not is pretty simple because it is just a single file. So using File.Exists is enough

Suppose that your MDB file is

```
Dim accessFilePath = "D:\temp\myDatabase.mdb"

If File.Exists(accessFilePath) Then
    ... file exists
End if
```

Of course getting the content of the file (in terms of **TABLES** and **QUERY**) is a different thing and requires to open the connection and get the SCHEMA informations

```
Dim cnnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & accessFilePath 

Using con = new OleDbConnection(cnnString)
    con.Open()
    Dim schema = con.GetSchema("Tables")
    For Each row As DataRow in schema.Rows
       Console.WriteLine(row.Field(Of String)("TABLE_NAME"))
    Next
End Using
```

See [how GetSchema works](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/schema-and-metadata-retrieval-using-ado.net/) and what are its possible parameters and results